# Webcam js Error in Chrome,firefox: Could not access webcam from remote client

Tags: localhost, client, webcam

I am using webcam.js in my php web based software and when we access using 'localhost/registration/create' then webcam.js works well and correct on the server machine, but when we access this software using

```
IP('192.168.10.10/registration/create' )
```

from the client machine in browser it gives error, [please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoE53.png).

```
Webcam.js Error: Could not access webcam: NotReadableError: Failed to allocate videosource NotReadableError: Failed to allocate videosource
```

I have tried a lot and search a lot but could not find the solution so please suggest me correct solution for this Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browser does not support user media calls from insecure URLs. So you can't use the camera or microphone from a web request that doesn't have SSL. Only these devices are accessible from localhost or HTTPS.

There is another way (not recommended) to solve this problem manually configure the web browsers.

```
chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure
```